# Entrance and exit animations are glitched

Tags: jquery, html, css

I made entrance/exit animations, which uses CSS3's `transition` property and jQuery's `queue`s.

One `div` is visible at start and the other `div` is hidden at start.

After running the code, I see that the exit occurs smoothly, but the entrance doesn't even happen. And after a few clicks, the `div`s disappear.

I want both the animations to play once per click, exit first.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".side").click(function() {
    $(this).css("transform", "rotate(90deg)");
    $(this).css("opacity", "0");
    $(this).css("margin-left", "50px");
    $(this).delay(400).queue(function() {
        $(this).hide();
        var nextTarg = $($(this).attr("next-target"));
        nextTarg.show();
        nextTarg.css("transform", "rotate(0deg)");
        nextTarg.css("opacity", "1");
        nextTarg.css("margin-left", "1.5%");
      });
  });
});
```

```css
.entrance {
  transition: 0.4s;
}
.box {
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  background-color: violet;
  margin: 1.5%;
}
.different.box {
  background-color: blueviolet;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.hidden.side {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  margin-left: 50px;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="side1" class="side entrance box" next-target="#side2"></div>
<div id="side2" class="different hidden side entrance box" next-target="#side1"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing a little bit of your *jQuery* and *CSS* will help you achieve that as:

### Code Snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".side").click(function() {
    $(this).css({
      'transform': 'rotate(90deg)',
      'opacity': 0,
      'margin-left': '50px',
    });
    $(this).delay(400).queue(function() {
      $(this).css({
        'visibility': 'hidden'
      });
      var nextTarg = $($(this).attr("next-target"));
      nextTarg.css({
        'visibility': 'visible',
        'transform': 'rotate(0deg)',
        'opacity': 1,
        'margin-left': '8px',
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.entrance {
  transition: 0.4s;
}
.parent {
  position: relative;
}
.box {
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  background-color: violet;
  margin: 8px;
}
.different.box {
  background-color: blueviolet;
  position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: -8px;
}
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.hidden.side {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  margin-left: 50px;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div id="side1" class="side entrance box" next-target="#side2"></div>
  <div id="side2" class="different hidden side entrance box" next-target="#side1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want the animations to be infinite, like, there shouldn't be a stop for the animations. Whenever I click the `div`, the other div must come.